# Can I reclaim unsold items in the Trade Depot?

Tags: simcity-buildit

I have some items in the Trade Depot that haven't sold yet.  I would like to reclaim them, is this possible?

I've tried the red trash button on the 'Edit Sale' UI. I used this with so some items I didn't mind losing and it seems like it discarded my items completely while costing a Simoleon for my trouble. I don't see anywhere else obvious that would allow me to reclaim these items. So are they out of my reach for good once they're in the Trade Depot?

Comment: Just leave them and in approximately 24 hours, the NPC city will buy everything that's left off you. But as [lemontwist mentions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/219276/90943) you can't ever get them back!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you put your items for sale on the global trade market, they are, for all intents and purposes, gone. You cannot get them back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a club there's an easy solution. You can ask a fellow member to buy it, then you can buy it back.